# Read sound from Assets folder (work with the android nexus 5 emulator but not on my phone)

Tags: android, directory, assets

I succeeded to run my function with the Android Emulator. The Assets folder is well recognised and all sounds files are in my Array allSounds.

But when i try to run my apk on my phone with ADB, my sounds folder in the Assets is empty. This function is on the main Activity.

Do you have any ideas to understand my problem ?

Thank's !!

```
 public void playRandom(View view) throws IOException {
        Resources res = getResources(); //if you are in an activity
        AssetManager aMan = res.getAssets();
        sounds = new ArrayList<>();
        String path = "sounds/";

        String folderNames[] =  aMan.list(path);
       // TextView debug = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.debug);
        //Evite de reCall la fonction si les sons sont déjà dans l'Array allSounds[]
        if (!flagDoNotRepeat) {
            for (String folderName : folderNames) {
                String[] fileNames = getAssets().list(path + folderName + "/");
                for (String file : fileNames) {
                    allSounds.add(path + folderName + "/" + file);
                    //debug.append("\n" + path + folderName + "/" + file);
                    flagDoNotRepeat = true;
                }
            }
        }
        m = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                if (m.isPlaying()) {
                    m.stop();
                    m.release();
                    m = new MediaPlayer();
                }

                AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = aMan.openFd(allSounds.get(new Random().nextInt(allSounds.size())));
                m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
                descriptor.close();

                m.prepare();
                m.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                m.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Edit : i resolved my problem :

```
 am = getAssets();

    String path = "sounds";

    String folderNames[] = new String[0];
    try {
        folderNames = am.list(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // TextView debug = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.debug);
    //Evite de reCall la fonction si les sons sont déjà dans l'Array allSounds[]
    if (!flagDoNotRepeat) {
        for (String folderName : folderNames) {
            String[] fileNames = new String[0];
            try {
                fileNames = am.list(path + "/" + folderName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (String file : fileNames) {
                allSounds.add(path + "/" + folderName + "/" + file);
                //debug.append("\n" + path + folderName + "/" + file);
                flagDoNotRepeat = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to use just **AssetManager aMan = getAssets();**

Comment: It's the same, i just tried.

Comment: one more try, change this String path = "sounds/"; to String path = "sounds";

Comment: It's the same. I think about the Context. I try to run with myContext.getAssets() => not working.

Comment: If someone have an idea ? :)

Comment: change the path from String path = "sounds/"; to String path = "sounds";

Comment: Yes i tried that, but it didn't work ... Thank's for your help !

Comment: I tried path without "/" gives me the results but if I try path with "/" gave me 0 results. Also make sure you are making a call like **AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();** not  AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();

Comment: I tried to, not working... i'm so desespered

Comment: String folderNames[] =  aMan.list(path); you get empty array right ??

Comment: You did not tell that the sounds folder contains subfolders. And that your files are only in the those subfolders.

Comment: If you changed path to sounds then use getAssets().list(path + "/" +folderName ); instead.

Comment: What version of Android are you using? You may need to request access via permission action in Android.

Comment: I solved my problem ! thx